# No me funciona mi enlace attr según click

Tags: javascript, html5, href

Tengo un JavaScript que abre varios enlace href="" ubicado a su vez en varios div, usando load y attr, pero no me funciona en un navegador; solamente en mi editor.

Mi HTML es así:

```
<!-- ubicación de enlaces -->
<div class=".ver" data-target="#yoVisor" href="Emma.html">
Ver artículo
</div>

<!-- destino de enlaces -->
<div class=".viendo"></div>
```

Y mi JavaScript es lo siguiente:

```
$(".ver").click(function(ev) {
 
 ev.preventDefault(); 
 
 $( $(this).attr("data-target") + ".viendo").load($(this).attr("href"), function() {
 
 $($(this).attr("data-target")); 
 
}
 
}
```

Por favor, necesito ayuda con este... Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery no encuentra donde mostrar el nuevo contenido, porque no tienes un elemento con ID `yoVisor`.

Además, el punto para especificar clases aplica solo en selectores CSS, no en atributos de etiquetas; sobra el punto en `<div class=".ver" data-target="#yoVisor" href="Emma.html">` y en `<div class=".viendo"></div>`, debiendo ser solo `class="ver"` o `class="viendo"`

Si el clic se hace en:

```
<div class="ver" data-target="#yoVisor" href="Emma.html">
```

Según lo que tienes en esta línea:

```
$($(this).attr("data-target") + ".viendo").load($(this).attr("href"));
```

El selector es `#yoVisor.viendo`, por lo que el elemento destino debe tener ID y clase:

```
<div id="yoViendo" class="viendo"></div>
```

Pero, como los [ID son únicos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), está de sobra crear el selector con ID y clase, es suficiente solo con ID:

```
$($(this).attr("data-target")).load($(this).attr("href"));
```

Omití la función (segundo parámetro de `load`) porque no estás ejecutando alguna acción. En caso de querer aplicar algún efecto, entonces sí es necesario agregar la función que va a ejecutarse cuando se complete la carga.

```
$('.ver').on('click', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    // Ocultar elemento antes de cargar
    $($(this).attr("data-target")).fadeOut();
    $($(this).attr("data-target")).load($(this).attr("href"), function() {
        // Mostrar al finalizar la carga de nuevo contenido
        $($(this).attr("data-target")).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

**Nota:** [$.click()](https://api.jquery.com/click/) es la forma corta de asignar eventos y se prefiere el uso de [$.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Ok. Tuve errores al escribir el código (porque no copié). Pero algo no me cuadra: al hacer click sobre .ver, no me carga el href en el div viendo.